# Unity Login Screen

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I already created the login client and server, now what I worry about is the design.
I don't like the design of the Unity default buttons and text fields, Can I change them somehow? Another thing I want is to display the logo and the text fields in the middle of the screen, no matter the size.
So with the text fields I have right now (default design) I did new Rect(Screen.Width / 2) and such, and it works, but how can I do like that with to logo?

I hope someone could help me <3

Comment: You have asked at least two separate questions here. You should separate your problem into multiple questions in order to get more clear answers. Also, it's worth pointing out that questions asking for software recommendations are considered offtopic for StackOverflow and would be closed.

Comment: Okay I edited to my main questions, can you help please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Unity GUI System! it's jucky, slow and missing a lot of features.

Use a proper GUI System like [NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140) or [Daikon Forge](http://www.daikonforge.com/dfgui/).

Or wait for Unity 4.6 to come out, they will introduce a new GUI System from the developer of NGUI.

**UPDATE 1**

I you want to use the Unity GUI System anyway, you can actually skin it. 
In the Project View, right click and select Create > [GUI Skin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-GUISkin.html), then modify it and assign it to your component.

```
[SerializeField]
GUISkin skin;

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(50,50,200,200),"Hello",skin.label);
}
```

Comment: While your recommendation is sound advice, you've not helped to answer any of the specific questions asked (either in standard Unity or in either of the systems you recommended).

Comment: @DanPuzey neither do you... ._. Thank you Jean, I'll see those GUIs, I hope they are easier than Unity GUI...

Comment: @SwordArt please don't use Unity GUI. invest the some money in something like NGUI, they even have a free version for testing if you are unsure.

Comment: @JeanLuc I cannot invest money right now, i'm a free user...
I have the free version, but I have no idea how to use it lol. I created Text Fields with my GUI and logo and background, isn't there any way to just customize it? I don't wanna learn a whole new GUI after I did all that ><

Comment: did you modify your GUI skin file? please read the documentation behind [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-GUISkin.html)